# iOS app has bugs when updated it on iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, xcode7

I have a strange problem with my app. I have finished the design and I am ready to update it on the store however, when I do that and I test my app using test flight the app is completely different from the version installed from xcode.

Some colors are different the are bugs that are not present when testing it on xcode and even the status bar that I have hidden is now visible..

I have other apps on the store and i never experienced this isuues and I am sure that I am uploading them right version of their app..

What could be going wrong?

Comment: Most probably you uploaded older build to iTunes.

Comment: I am sure not because on any of the builds I have the status bar is visible.

Comment: Have you tried running a release build using Xcode?

Comment: How can install And run a release build? Every time I try to install a release version xcode doesn't let me